# Ошибка в подключении кнопки URL в Телеграмм боте

Tags: telegram-bot, url

При подключении кнопки URL в Controller bote выдаёт ошибку. Не пойму что не так с написанием. Я не программист, прошу скидку

Это инструкция:
Отправьте мне список URL-кнопок в одном сообщении. Пожалуйста, следуйте этому формату:

Кнопка 1 - http://example1.com
Кнопка 2 - http://example2.com

Это текст моей кнопки:

История переезда - https://telegra.ph/Moya-istoriya-pereezda-03-21

Это код ошибки

Некорректная клавиатура: inline keyboard button URL is invalid

Исправьте ошибку и пришлите еще раз.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие вопроса, потому что он не связан с программированием.

Answer (score 0):

Надо написать Отмена, затем Enter и написать пост заново. Тоже было такое